How to Visualize the Component Tree in Flame's FCS for Easier Debugging?
In Flame's Component System (FCS), it's common to add or remove components at runtime. To better understand the current state of the component tree, I want to visualize this information using debug prints or tools.
After running $ flutter run in the terminal, I entered v to bring up the debug tools. It seems that there are 168 components, but I find it difficult to get a clear overview because I need to click through each part of the tree individually. Is there a way to display the entire component tree using a print statement or some other method for easier debugging?
The code I tried is https://github.com/ufrshubham/ski_master


Also, this tree is not updated in real-time (it refreshes when the browser is refreshed). As shown in the attached image, there is a reload button, but it is disabled and does not respond when clicked(This button does not respond, the tree is updated when the browser is refreshed).


Your question is a bit vague, what is it that you want to print to the terminal, like how do you want it to look like?

@spydon I am a web and regular Flutter developer, and I am just starting to gain personal experience in game development. I am used to working with RESTful Web APIs and viewing results in JSON format. However, I am not familiar with the development experience where objects are added to the game loop and processed every frame. Therefore, I want to confirm whether objects are actually being added. It would be helpful if I could paste the data into an editor I am familiar with, like VSCode, and search for keywords using commands like Command + F, similar to working with JSON.

You can use component.propagateToChildren to quite easily print the tree structure. Another note, remember that children aren't added to the tree until the tick is over, and not directly when you call add.
